# Two JMX intefaces on the same host : How duplicate JMX items?

Tags: monitoring, jmx, zabbix

On a host, there is two Java app runing, exposing JMX data (App 1 : JBoss Wildfly. App2 : Apache Tomcat)

I set up two JMX interfaces in the Host config on the Zabbix server. Now, I want to create some items that will get the JVM data? e.g :

```
jmx["java.lang:type=ClassLoading",LoadedClassCount]
```

I can't create two items with the same key. How can I by-pass this contol ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: there is no solution for this.

Long answer:

## Why you might not want to do it

Due to a bug https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-4677 , Zabbix does not handle multiple interfaces of the same type properly.
If one of the interfaces is unavailable (like a JVM being slow or down), Zabbix stops monitoring other interfaces of the same type.

## Doing it anyway

### Hacking this manually in the configuration

You can manually edit items to make keys different - for example, adding a space after that comma would make the key different, but it would work the same way still. Of course, that completely defeats templating and is not sustainable beyond a couple of items.

### Hacking this in the Java gateway source

You can hack Java gateway to ignore the third parameter. This way LLD can place port as the third parameter (and also in the JMX URL), making the keys unique.

https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-4510 asked for the change to be included in the gateway, but was rejected.

## Feature requests

These feature requests might solve your need, but the best you can do is vote on them.

- https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-735 asks for item uniqueness to change from host to interface.
- https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1983 asks for a port parameter in JMX items, allowing to use LLD directly.